# Extremely slow connection (18.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 18.04, connection

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my ASUS X555LA. I was using Windows 10 and everything worked kinda fine, but I've been having some troubles with my connection since I installed Ubuntu.
At first, it wouldn't recognize the wireless card and I couldn't connect to the wi-fi (my card is a MediaTek MT7630E). After doing some research, I could finally fix it. Now, the problem is: even though the wi-fi works fine, the connection is still EXTREMELY slow. Like, 100 kb/s. It should be around 10-20 mb/s. I couldn't find any solution on Google. 
Could you please help me? 
Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
    *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: enp2s0
   version: 10
   serial: 1c:b7:2c:9d:8e:11
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b2104000-b2104fff memory:b2100000-b2103fff

    *-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0f0
   version: 00
   serial: 40:b8:9a:76:7b:dd
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7630e driverversion=4.15.0-34-generic firmware=112.3 ip=192.168.1.8 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:b2000000-b20fffff
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Add the output of  `iwconfig  wlp4s0` to your post. If  wlp4s0 isn't your wlan card, find it with `ip l`, and replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheking "Make available to other users" in the settings of the network you are connected has worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to edit this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also How do I write a good answer? for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disabling IPv6

Go to `Settings -> Network tab -> Wired -> IPv6 -> disable -> Apply -> Restart`

[image: disable_ipv6_screenshot]